# How should I display spinner image when response taking a while

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am totally newbie User Interface Development, Can you please some one tell me how should I display the spinner/loading graphic image before the response came to the browser.

I just tried something using JQuery library like as follows:

```
$("#signupdialog").dialog({
            title : 'Sign-up Popup',
            width : 500,
            height: 550,
            buttons: [
                      {
                          text : 'Sign-up',
                          icons: {
                                    primary: "btn-primary"
                                 },
                          click : function(){
                              var fname = $("#userFirstName").val();
                              var lname = $("#userLastName").val();
                              var email = $("#userEmail").val();
                              var pwd = $("#userPwd").val();
                              $.get("../../rest/user/save",{
                                            fname: fname,
                                            lname: lname,
                                            email: email,
                                            pwd : pwd
                                        },function(data,status){
                                            $("#result").html("<img src='../images/ajax-loader.gif' height='100px'width='100px'>");
                                            if(status == 'success'){
                                                $("#result").html('');
                                                $("#result").html("<font color='green'>"+data+"</font>");
                                            }
                                });
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          text : 'Cancel',
                          icons: {
                                    primary: "btn-warning"
                                 },
                          click : function(){
                              $(this).dialog("close");
                          }
                      }
                      ],
            closeText : 'CLOSE',
            autoOpen : false,
            modal : true,
            draggable : false,
            resizable : false
    });
```

By this I got only simply "saved" message (What I wrote in the server side language) after the save operation status 200 came. But here I need to insert the spinner graphic file before the save operation It means save operation in progress

Can you please someone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the

```
$("#result").html("<img src='../images/ajax-loader.gif' height='100px'width='100px'>");
```

line above the $.get line